# Init.d service not respawning after kill

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have the following init.d script running on Ubuntu 14.04

```
# Logstash Service

description     "Logstash"

start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems
          and runlevel [2345])

stop on runlevel [016]

respawn limit 10 5

# NB: Upstart scripts do not respect
# /etc/security/limits.conf, so the open-file limits
# settings need to be applied here.
limit nofile 32000 32000

console output

setuid tps

chdir /opt/logstash-1.4.2

env LS_HOME=/opt//logstash-1.4.2

env CONFIG_DIR=/opt/config/logstash
env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-x64
env SINCEDB_DIR=/opt/config/logstash
env _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
exec $LS_HOME/bin/logstash -f $CONFIG_DIR -vvv | svlogd /opt/logs 2>&1
```

When I manually kill it by executing `kill -9 <pid>` the process doesn't respawn. Is there a way to tell it to respawn if terminated?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't tell it to respawn.

As the Upstart Cookbook [says](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn-limit),

> ### 6.28   `respawn`
>
> With this stanza, whenever the main script/exec exits, without the goal of the job having been changed to stop, the job will be started again.
>
> ### 6.29   `respawn limit`
>
> Yes, this is *different* to a plain respawn: specifying `respawn limit` does not imply `respawn`.

In other words, you must set `respawn` even if you also have `respawn limit`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the inittab file to tell it to respawn.

An entry in it looks like this: id:runlevels:action:process

respawn can be set as one of the actions.

Comment: While this answer is alright, it is also a bit outdated – Ubuntu's Upstart only has a minimal inittab for compatibility, and systemd does not read it at all.

Comment: Actually, it's not alright.  upstart ignores inittab too.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196197/5132 .